# Merging two csv files

Tags: sql, database, csv, database-schema

Im fairly new to databases and programming. Im trying to find an easy way to combine data from two csv files. Are there any tools that would help doing this? What I'm ultimately trying to do is combine these two tables into 1 big table so I can run scripts on it.

Comment: Have a look at [LINQ-To-CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library)

Comment: Do the files have the same format?  If so, you can just concat the files at the operating system level.  You can import them into Excel, if they are not too big, and do the manipulation there.  You can import them into a database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two .csv files are in the same format and are really comma-separated-values text files, you can combine the two files using cat on Linux and the appropriate tool on Windows. Then, you can load the resultant, combined .csv file into the database's table.

You could also do two separate loads, one for each of the .csv files, using your database managers load tool. This assumes the database table employs a unique key and and the two .csv files do not contain duplicate data.